# JavaScript: Making an If statement adjust to a variable after adding to it

Tags: javascript, html, function, datetime, if-statement

I am creating a HTML/JavaScript page that displays world clocks, However I ran into a problem with the clocks not adjusting to the AM/PM correctly, and also not staying in the standard time format. I realize this is because the if statement that makes the session change to = 'PM' only works for the time zone it gets. Also my code only gets the time and puts it in the California slot because that is the time zone I am in, so if you open this code in a time zone other than pacific time, all of the world clocks will be incorrect. Is it possible to keep my clocks in a standard time format and also be the correct AM or PM?

```js
let clock = document.getElementById('clock');

function currentTime() {

  let date = new Date();
  let hours = date.getHours();
  let minutes = date.getMinutes();
  let seconds = date.getSeconds();
  let session = 'AM';

  if (hours == 0) {
    hours = 12
  }
  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12
    session = 'PM'
  }

  minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  let time = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('clock').innerText = time;

  let york = (hours + 3) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('york').innerText = york;

  let hawaii = (hours - 2) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('hawaii').innerText = hawaii;

  let dubai = (hours + 12) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('dubai').innerText = dubai;

  document.getElementById('seconds').innerText = ':' + seconds;

  let london = (hours + 8) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('london').innerText = london;

  let moscow = (hours + 12) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('moscow').innerText = moscow;

  let paris = (hours + 9) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('paris').innerText = paris;

  let tokyo = (hours + 17) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + session;
  document.getElementById('tokyo').innerText = tokyo;

  let t = setTimeout(function() {
    currentTime()
  }, 1000);
}

currentTime();
```

```css
p {line-height: 0.5em}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="clockContainer">
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">California <span id="clock" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">New York <span id="york" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">Hawaii <span id="hawaii" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="clockContainer">
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">Dubai <span id="dubai" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">Seconds <span id="seconds" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">London <span id="london" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="clockContainer">
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">Tokyo <span id="tokyo" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">Paris <span id="paris" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
    <div id="titleContainer">
      <p id="title">Moscow <span id="moscow" class='clock'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) with various options, including *timeZone*, which is specified using an [IANA representative location](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). You can also use [*formatToParts*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) to get the components then format them however you like, including 12/24 hour time and am/pm, e.g.

```js
function formatDate(date, loc) {
  let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en',{
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour12: true,
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    timeZone: loc,
    timeZoneName: 'long'
  });
  let {year, month, day, hour, minute, dayPeriod, timeZoneName} = f.formatToParts(date).reduce((parts, part) => {
    parts[part.type] = part.value;
    return parts;
  }, Object.create(null));
  
  return `${day} ${month} ${year} ${hour}:${minute} ${dayPeriod.toLowerCase()} ${timeZoneName}`;
}

let d = new Date();
document.querySelectorAll('.clockTime').forEach(el =>
  el.textContent = formatDate(d, el.dataset.loc)
);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Place<th>Date and time
  <tr>
    <td>Kiritimati <td class="clockTime" data-loc="Pacific/Kiritimati">
  <tr>
   <td>Lord Howe Is <td class="clockTime" data-loc="Australia/Lord_Howe">
  <tr>
   <td>India <td class="clockTime" data-loc="Asia/Kolkata">
  <tr>
    <td>Dubai <td class="clockTime" data-loc="Asia/Dubai">
  <tr>
    <td>London <td class="clockTime" data-loc="Europe/London">
  <tr>
   <td>Los Angeles <td class="clockTime" data-loc="America/Los_Angeles">
  <tr>
   <td>Midway Is<td class="clockTime" data-loc="Pacific/Midway">
</table>
```

The only real issue is that setting *timeZoneName* to short does not reliably return an abbreviation of the long time zone name. Depending on the location and language, it may return an abbreviation or the actual offset as UTC/GMT±HH:mm. So if you want the abbreviated timezone name, best to get the full name and abbreviate it yourself (which isn't always just the first letters of the time zone name, e.g. Chatham Standard Time is "ChSt").

Answer (score -1):

Try the moment js library.

It will help you with date,time management, form, calculations, and more.

good luck.

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // December 17th 2021, 2:54:05 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Friday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Dec 17th 21
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2021 escaped 2021
moment().format();                          // 2021-12-17T14:54:05+09:00
```

https://momentjs.com/

Comment: From the momentJS site: https://momentjs.com/docs/ and https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/02/14/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-anymore They no longer recommend using moment. Rather look at using alternatives in the first link

Answer (score -1):

You can also try using the [getUTCHours()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours) function on the date object to standardize the time that you're getting and work from there.

The reason why the AM/PM switch is not working for you is because you are just checking the initial `hours` value. You should check it for every timezone that you want and add the AM or PM suffix accordingly.
For example: `let york = (hours + 3) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + (hours + 3 > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");`

I hope this helps.

Comment: How does that help the OP determine whether it's am or pm at a particular location?

Comment: @RobG It does not, but it helps the OP standardize time so that it shows up consistently everywhere.
OP - you can do something like this:  
`let york = (hours + 3) + ':' + minutes + ' ' + (hours + 3 > 12 ? "PM" : "AM");`  
and it should give you the desired effect.  
Edit: The reason why AM/PM did not work was that you only change the session if the initial `hours` variable is > 12. You have to check it in every case so it can be properly applied.

Comment: You should put that comment into the answer.